# ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewContact"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contactOuterLayout"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contactOuterRelativeLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/radialback">



            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                     
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1" 
                android:paddingBottom="10sp">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contactdetails"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >
                        
                    <TableRow 
                        android:id="@+id/mapView"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        >
                        <LinearLayout 
                            android:id="@+id/liny"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="100">

                            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                                 android:id="@+id/map"
                                 android:layout_height="100dp"
                                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                 android:enabled="true"
                                 android:clickable="true"
                                 android:apiKey="00n1pmS8eEhXhD5a6Q3UTDd6zortw9t4l_jXioQ"
                                />
                            
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MapAdrress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:text="TextView" />
                            
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </TableRow>
                    
                                                            
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        

                        
                        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/contactinfo" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            

                            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/contactinfo2" 
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                    <!-- Telephone number, web-site etc -->         
                                </TableLayout>                                                                      
                            </TableRow> 

            
                        
                    </TableLayout>              
                        
                    </TableRow> 
                    
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        
                        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/contactinfo" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            
                            >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/butonek"
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             />
            
                    </TableLayout>
                        
                    </TableRow>

                    
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="20dip">
                        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">                                   
                            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/address" 
                                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                    <!-- Address -->
                                </TableLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>
                    </TableRow>                     
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="20dip">
                                        <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/contactlist"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                     android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                     />

                    </TableRow> 
                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This is picture:

[image]

I have 4 elements on list but I can see only two and can't scroll. How I can do this to scroll all page not only list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <ListView
                 android:id="@+id/contactlist"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                 android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                 />
                 </LinearLayout>
```

In this case I put listView inside linearlayout and this solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have your ListView inside a ScrollView. Since ListView has its own implementation for Scrolling, having it inside of a ScrollView will affect its Scroll as well as your ScrollView. So replace your layout in such a way that you don't have your ListView inside the ScrollView.

Comment: but when I put listView outside scrollView one part page will be scrollable and listView have our scroll. I want to all page will be scrollable.

Comment: Yeah this is really frustrating I know. You can simply use a table layout and add dynamic views to it. Its not much difficult to do. Try and let me know. But that's the only way to do, without changing your screen design.

Comment: ok, I solve my problem, but other way. My listView put inside Linear layout and it works perfectly. Thx for advice and help.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a better implementation to add your listview inside a scrollview. when you have a listview within the scrollview and when you scroll the listview its very difficult for android to make difference and the scroll will be consumed by the scrollview though you scroll the listview and hence the items in your listview wont be lifted up. So you replace your scroll view by Linear layout.

Also by looking at your layout design it can be found that many of the layouts are not really needed. Its better you review your design. Lint can help you out in removing the unnecessary layouts.